# Eagle >Label attribute (in some Adafruit parts)

Tags: eaglecad, footprint

I'm using an SMA edge launch connector from Adafruit's part library. Alongside the usual `>NAME` and `>VALUE` text it also has `>LABEL` which I've not seen before. I can't see an obvious way of assigning the text and I can't remove it from the footprint like a name/value as it's baked into `tplace`. I've just removed it from the footprint.

The question is simply - does `>LABEL` mean something in Eagle?

For example (here `WIFI_1` is the part value)

[image]

Comment: You should be able to open up the Attributes for the part and assign a value there. You can also turn it off if you don't want to see it. Also, depending on what antenna part you are using, it looks like you may have it misplaced. The large yellow area may need to be completely off the board. Check the part dimensions before you send this to be manufactured (looks like it could be offset during assembly though, but better to have it right on the board than fix it in assembly).

Comment: I've not used the Label attribute in any PCB design I've done or symbol I created. >Name and >Value have been sufficient for the parts. I have added extra Text to boards, putting it on the Top Place or Bottom Place layers, Top Name or Bottom Name, I'd have to go look now to confirm. Board house has never questioned a lack of >Label info in the Gerber files

Comment: Thanks @Ron Beyer, it's not off to the fab yet. It does need to be further out, but I wondered why the silkscreen was placed there by default. I think the main reason was I got DRC errors with OshPark if I placed the pads at the edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign a value, you simply have to set the corresponding attribute.

For `LABEL` then you would create a new attribute for the part in the schematic using the `attribute` command, set the name of the attribute as `LABEL` and the value as whatever you want.

Eagle will then replace the text `>LABEL` in the layout (and/or schematic) with the corresponding attribute value.

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick. For others interested, for reference it seems like when a `>` placeholder is added to a footprint, once you define an attribute it also allows you to move the text on the board. If you don't define an attribute value, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to hide or move it.